# Notice: Undefined index: comment in C:\xampp\htdocs\index\comment.php on line 5

Tags: php, html, comments

So I have this code:

```
    <?php

if($_POST){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $content = $_POST['comment'];
    $handle = fopen("comments.html","a");
    fwrite($handle,"<b>" . $name . "</b><br />" . $content . "<br />");
    fclose($handle);
}

?>


<html>
<head>
<title>Comment box test</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="POST">

Name<br />
<input type="text" name="name">
<br />
Comment<br />
<textarea rows="3" cols="22" name"comment"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><br />

</form>

<?php include "comments.html"; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Every time after I try to post a comment in my "comments.php" page I get the error just like in my title, and only the name appears, not name + comment. I can't find the error in the code since I'm a very newbie in PHP. If someone could help me I'll appreciate that!

Comment: name="comment" instead of name"comment" should help.

Comment: Check your code before you post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html, the equal-sign is missing in your comment textarea.

So

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="22" name"comment"></textarea>
```

Must be

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="22" name="comment"></textarea>
```

Because of that the comment is not being posted correctly. Since you are trying to access the index 'comment' in the $_POST array, but it does not exist, php throws the notice 'index does not exist'

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

Change

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="22" name"comment"></textarea>
```

to

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="22" name="comment"></textarea>
```

### Suggestion

You'll eventually get to a point where you've got the basics of PHP. I would suggest taking a look at [W3Schools MYSQL PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) as this is a much better way of storing comments. You'll be able to filter them & its much more secure.

Good luck!

Comment: You are recommending a site which examples depreciated libraries in PHP and more over, unsanatized queries which are vulnerable to injection. -1

Comment: I highly disagree and multiple developers who are apart of this community do also. Your free to check with the Chat on PHP on this site for their views

Answer (score 0):

Is missing an equal sign =

That causes the POST comment element to not be defibed